# How to make elements not under/overlaping, other elements with position:fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css

im trying to make a menu that has a header, nav, aside, and a section.
The way that i organize them is on the figure bellow.

Has you can see on the image bellow:

- The aside.style.top is connected to bottom of nav via javascript.
  Works fine..
- The aside.style.width changes with the window.innerWidth, being 15%
  of window.innerWidth, with a max of 250px, and when the
  window.innerWidth is lower that 750px the element disapears. Works
  fine....
- Now is where the problem begins on the section when i try to make the
  section not go into the gap left by the aside(position:fixed), I do on
  js:  section.style.left = aside.clientWidth; but this seems to have no
  effect on the section.

I also tryed to change the margin,padding of section and also has no effect.

Bellow are two images that try to represent what i just wrote.
The first one is what should happen, the second one is what happens.

At last i have the brute code in case, you want to try it.

Any help Appreciated.

[image: Image representing what is should happen]

[image: Image representing what is happening, and what i pretende to]

Brute Code:

```
<doctype html>

<html >
<head>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pageStyle.css">-->
    <style>
    body{
        margin:0px;
    }
    header{
        position:relative;
        top:0px;
        text-align:center;
        background-color:blue;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
        width:100%;
        display:block;
        font-size:15px;
    }
    nav{
        position:sticky;
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        display:block;
        top:0px;
        width:100%;
        display:block;
    }
    aside{
        left:0px;
        top:0px;
        height:100%;

        position:fixed;
        overflow:auto;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    section{
        position:relative;
        margin-left:100px;
    }

    input[type="color"]{
        border:none;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
    }
    table.table1{
        margin:auto;
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border:1px solid black;
    }



    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header" style="background-color:green">
        <div>
            Make by The BOSS &copy <br />
            And the Dum one
        </div>
    </header>
    <nav class="nav" id="horMenu" style="background-color:blue">
        <div><span style="font-size:550px;">Nav Div</span></div>

    </nav>

    <aside class="aside" id="leftMenu" style="background-color:gray">
        <div>
            sdfsdfsdf
        </div>

    </aside>
    <div class="section" id="sectionMenu" style="background-color:orange">
        section
        <div class="article" style="background-color:brown">
            <div>
                article
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer" style="background-color:red">
            <div>
                footer
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script>
        //variables, secton, nav, aside

        window.addEventListener("scroll", stick, false);
        window.addEventListener("load", stick, false);
        var naveMenuId = document.getElementById("horMenu");
        var leftMenuId = document.getElementById("leftMenu");
        var sectionId = document.getElementById("sectionMenu");

        //function for make the aside stick to bottom of nav
        function stick(){

            var pos = naveMenuId.clientHeight;
            pos += naveMenuId.getBoundingClientRect().top;

            leftMenuId.style.top = pos;
        }
        window.addEventListener("resize", resize_x, false);
        window.addEventListener("load", resize_x, false);
        //function to resize aside width with relation to innerWith
        function resize_x(e){

            if(window.innerWidth < 727){
                leftMenuId.style.width = "0px";
                leftMenuId.style.display = "none";  
            }else{
                leftMenuId.style.display = "block";
                var elemWidth = window.innerWidth * 0.15;

                if(elemWidth >= 150){
                    leftMenuId.style.width = "150px";
                }else{
                    leftMenuId.style.width = "15%";
                }
            }

            //code to try to mak section not under lapping the aside
            sectionId.style.width = naveMenuId.getBoundingClientRect().right;

        }

    </script>


    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
```

Comment: Usually, I just add a margin to the non-fixed element.

Comment: Positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Use `@media` queries, you don't need all that JS just to do a little bit of viewport-resize fixing!